# Grails project unable to resolve org.junit

Tags: java, maven, grails, junit

I have checked a maven-based project, and for some reason I can't get over compilation of testing classes. Even if I create a new test through a grails command, I can't compile it.

The error I'm getting is `Error:Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.junit.Assert` on code

```
import exchange.TimetableController
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(TimetableController)
@Mock([Person,Parallel,Course,Event,RestService])
class TimetableControllerSpec extends Specification {
(...)
```

.. when I delete both @TestFor and @Mock annotations, the file gets compiled. Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

Review your pom file. Ensure it has the junit dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

You may want to do a grails refresh-dependencies after this too if you are trying to build within an IDE. Command line should be ok.

Comment: what for those who is not using maven I mean what with gradle

Comment: With gradle, just add it as a dependency:      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'